# Bash Script that will send data into MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, bash

I am new but not exactly. What I mean is that I go through this forum quiet a lot to search for answers, but I never really ask my own questions.

I have looked for similar problems here as well as on other websites, but without much luck.

Let me describe the problem.
I have to create a script that will send data into MySQL database, based on a file that is created by another script. The database is meant to hold data such MAC addresses, Identification numbers, Names, etc. The file that is created by another script, has that data, and "all" I need to do is get this data transfered over to the database. The problem that I have, is that this is supposed to happen automatically, rather than through the process of logging into data base and executing commands manually.

I have to say that I do not have much experience with MySQl databases and it is kind of problematic for me when it comes to resolving problems of this kind.

I have created a little "script" in bash, that I hoped would do what I described above. I wrote the script based on what I have found on the Internet, and with my very narrow understanding of MySQL I am not able to improve on it, so please don't be too judgmental :)

```
#!/bin/bash

mysql -u root -p

LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/kiot/Deskotp/Patryk/Imp0'
INTO TABLE KIOT
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

I always try to understand the code that I am using, so the file Imp0 looks like this :

```
"somedata",
"somemoredata",
"evenmoredata",
```

when I execute the code ( yes I have made it executable ) the terminal prompts me to enter a password for user root in the database, and when I enter it, it does nothing. When i use to command to display columns in the table KIOT, the data that I am trying to send does not appear there.

I am sorry for making this really long, but I am trying to be as informative as possible, so that everyone can understand my problem.

For anyone who is happy to help, I am truly grateful.
Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

This line `#!/bin/bash` at the top of your script tells the program loader to run the rest of your script in the bash interpreter. So when you run `mysql -u root -p` and log in, the script you are running will wait until you return from execution of the mysql program before it executes the rest of your script.

It looks like you need to use a `here document`. Here's a [link](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument?action=show&redirect=HereString) that should help you get started with it. Your script should work if you implement that correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is only one SQL command to execute here, another possibility would be to use the `-e` switch:

```
mysql -u root -p -e "LOAD DATA INFILE...;"
```

The challenge is then escaping the quote characters `"` and `'` correctly.

Also note that `-p` will *prompt* for the password. To run it completely unattended you can supply the password on the commandline (*without* a space between `-p` and `PASSWORD`):

```
mysql -u root -pPASSWORD -e "LOAD..."
```

This works but is not recommended (for security reasons). Perhaps connect with a dedicated MySQL user that is only granted the LOAD DATA access rights (instead of root).